# is there a way to verify Firebase Dynamic Links on Play Console?

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-play-console, firebase-dynamic-links, verify

I have a [Firebase Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) on my app. Seems that Play Console can not [verify](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#unverified-apps) these links by default.

[image: Play Console]

The [indexing](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing) is fine since I can manually bind/add the App Link of my app through Android settings.

[image: App Link]

Since the website domain is provided by Firebase, which means I can not upload a Digital Asset json, would there be a way to fix these links in my console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Debugging my dynamic link I realized that SHA256 was lacking.**

[image: Dynamic Link Debug]

[After some research](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#common_errors_and_warnings), I understood it was required to copy the app signing key certificate into the firebase project. This fingerprint can be found under **Play Console > Setup > App Integrity**.

[image: App Integrity]

Under Firebase Project Settings, add the fingerprint:

[image: Firebase Settings]

Hovering the `Type` tooltip, you will also find this message:

```
Firebase supports 2 types of certificate fingerprints:
SHA-1: Used to create OAuth 2 client and API key for your app
SHA-256: Used for configuring Firebase Dynamic links
```

*Note 1: Also add your SHA-1 key, might avoid OAuth future problems.*

*Note 2: Make sure you explicitly set `android:autoVerify` to `true`, on your intent responsible for filtering the dynamic link, thus your app link will be [auto-verified](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#add-intent-filters) once clicked.*

[image]

Comment: Did you then have to run a build for the message in play console to disappear?